# Giving error as "PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID" on payment execution even if the state of the payment is in "approved" state

Tags: paypal, payment, sandbox, postman, execute

On Execution of the payment giving error as

```
{
  "name": "PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID",
  "message": "Request is invalid for current payment state.",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID",
  "debug_id": "621987c99cbee"
}
```

The Payment is already in approve state
Response for the payment is

```
{
  "id": "PAY-49H97458KE3710939LELKB4Q",
  "create_time": "2017-05-13T06:00:18Z",
  "update_time": "2017-05-13T06:00:22Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "type": "xxxx",
          "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "expire_month": "x",
          "expire_year": "xxxx",
          "first_name": "xxxxxxxx",
          "last_name": "xxxxx"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "0.01",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "0.01"
        }
      },
      "description": "The payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "7NF6682256719761C",
            "create_time": "2017-05-13T06:00:18Z",
            "update_time": "2017-05-13T06:00:22Z",
            "amount": {
              "total": "0.01",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "state": "completed",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-49H97458KE3710939LELKB4Q",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/7NF6682256719761C",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/7NF6682256719761C/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-49H97458KE3710939LELKB4Q",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-49H97458KE3710939LELKB4Q",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

And giving the response as approved because of using the credit card. Is it the valid scenario? On using the payment method as "PayPal" response is showing as payment created.
And is there any api for transfer of money from one paypal account to another through sandbox?
And also is there any api to add the debit/ credit/ bank to our account?

Answer (score 0):

In REST API PayPal, there will be two types of payment acceptance which are ;

1. Credit Card
2. PayPal

If you are using PayPal, you need an additional execute API while if you are using Credit Card, you does not need execute API because the payment is already complete.